# Maven version dependency management

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, version, pom.xml

Suppose I 'm dealing with the following situation:

- My Maven Project uses version a of library X

  => X uses version b of library Y
- My Project also directly needs version b+1 of library Y

Now cosidering how Maven manages version conflicts,
only version b+1 of Y would be considered, and if Y is not a back compatible   library, the library X would likely fail to work properly...How do you usually resolve situations like this ?

EDIT:

I don't get how both at compile time and run-time MyProject would be provided with version b+1 of Y, while library X with version b ??

Comment: if it so how can both the java compiler and the jvm know wich to use when encountering for example a symbol like com.y.mylibrary.MyClass ?

Comment: I still don't get how bot at compile time and run-time MyProject would be provided with version b+1 of Y, while library X with version b ??

Comment: There was a question regarding this yesterday: [_Dependency convergence error_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36725439/1744774).